# Adding cron jobs using crontab from several different files

Tags: cron, amazon-linux

I have two files where in I have listed my cronjobs:

```
cron.dev1.txt
cron.dev2.txt
```

Now I am using `crontab` in the following manner:

`crontab cron.dev1.txt` and

`crontab cron.dev2.txt`

When I do `crontab -e`, I see that only the jobs listed in `crontab cron.dev2.txt` are listed. It seems that first the jobs in `crontab cron.dev1.txt` are loaded and then replaced by `crontab cron.dev2.txt`.

Is there a way to load jobs using crontab listed in several different files.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crontab(1)` man page notes you can populate the crontab via stdin:

> ```
>   The  first  form  of this command is used to install a new crontab from
>   some named file or standard  input  if  the  pseudo-filename  ``-''  is
>   given.
> ```

So we can do this:

```
$ cat cron.dev1.txt
* * * * * /bin/script1
$ cat cron.dev2.txt
* * * * * /bin/script2
$ cat cron.dev*.txt | crontab -
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /bin/script1
* * * * * /bin/script2
$
```